# Properly position a drop down div

Tags: html, css

I have an input field that acts as a search bar for my web app. When the user begins typing, with JQuery, a #search-suggestions div appears and is populated with suggestions using AJAX. Now, I took out the JQUERY and AJAX for my JSFIDDLE, but normally the div is hidden until you start typing (I just made it visible for example). How can I place the #search-suggestions div directly under the input? What is the proper css?

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/nFEnz/

CSS:

```
#search-suggestions {
padding: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
height: auto;
width: 298px;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
background-color: #fff;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: add `clear: both` to `#search-suggestions`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
http://jsfiddle.net/nFEnz/9/

```
#search {
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    height: 28px;
    width: 293px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: #EEE 0px 2px 6px 0px inset;
    background-color: #fff;
    position:relative;
}

#search input {
    float: left;
    outline: none;
    height: 28px;
    width: 265px;
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
    font-family: calibri;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #777;
}

#search-icon {
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;    
    height: 28px;
    width: 28px;
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
}

#search-icon img {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
}

#search-suggestions {
    padding: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
    height: auto;
    width: 298px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    background-color: #fff;
    position:absolute;
    top:31px;
}

#loading-suggestions {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
}

#loading-suggestions img {
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
}

.search-suggestion {
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    height: auto;
    width: 278px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.search-suggestion:last-child {
    padding: 5px 10px 0px 10px;
}

.search-suggestion-picture {
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.search-suggestion-picture img {
    height: auto;
    min-height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}

.search-suggestion-stuff {
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
}

.search-suggestion-name {
    height: 50px;
    width: auto;
}

.search-suggestion a {
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    font-family: calibri;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #444;
    line-height: 50px;
}

.search-suggestion a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the `#search` to be `position:relative` and the `#search-suggestions` to be `position:absolute` and have a `top:100%`.

```
#search {
    ... /*your current styles*/

    position:relative; /*ADDED THIS LINE*/
}

#search-suggestions {
    ... /*your current styles*/

    position:absolute; /*ADDED THIS LINE*/
    top:100%; /*ADDED THIS LINE*/
    left:0; /*ADDED THIS LINE*/
}
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/nFEnz/7/